# How to re arrange or order of table columns in vTiger?

Tags: php, vtiger

I want to change the order of column in vtiger tables in page leads 
i wanted the last name column to be the first in the table column 
instead of the first name can this be change in codes of database ?

[image]

Comment: which version of vtiger you are using ? In the newer version you should be able to arrange them from the setting section .

Comment: i am using the new version vtigerCRM600 but i dont want to change it in the setting section , just in the codes or database

Answer (score 0):

You can do it from database if you want.
Checkout the table called `vtiger_cvcolumnlist` and here the display order is maintained.
The table looks like

```
+------+-------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| cvid | columnindex | colu

    mnname                                                                                                  |
    +------+-------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
    |    1 |           0 | vtiger_leaddetails:lead_no:lead_no:Leads_Lead_No:V                                                          |
    |    1 |           1 | vtiger_leaddetails:lastname:lastname:Leads_Last_Name:V                                                      |
    |    1 |           2 | vtiger_leaddetails:firstname:firstname:Leads_First_Name:V                                                   |
    |    1 |           3 | vtiger_leaddetails:company:company:Leads_Company:V                                                          |
    |    1 |           4 | vtiger_leadaddress:phone:phone:Leads_Phone:V                                                                |
    |    1 |           5 | vtiger_leadsubdetails:website:website:Leads_Website:V                                                       |
    |    1 |           6 | vtiger_leaddetails:email:email:Leads_Email:E                                                                |
    |    1 |           7 | vtiger_crmentity:smownerid:assigned_user_id:Leads_Assigned_To:V                                             |
    |    2 |           0 | vtiger_leaddetails:firstname:firstname:Leads_First_Name:V                                                   |
    |    2 |           1 | vtiger_leaddetails:lastname:lastname:Leads_Last_Name:V                                                      |
    |    2 |           2 | vtiger_leaddetails:company:company:Leads_Company:V                                                          |
    |    2 |           3 | vtiger_leaddetails:leadsource:leadsource:Leads_Lead_Source:V                                                |
    |    2 |           4 | vtiger_leadsubdetails:website:website:Leads_Website:V                                                       |
    |    2 |           5 | vtiger_leaddetails:email:email:Leads_Email:E                                                                |
    |    3 |           0 | vtiger_leaddetails:firstname:firstname:Leads_First_Name:V                                                   |
    |    3 |           1 | vtiger_leaddetails:lastname:lastname:Leads_Last_Name:V                                                      |
    |    3 |           2 | vtiger_leaddetails:company:company:Leads_Company:V                                                          |
```

Usually the filter ALL is not editable from the front end so you need to change it from DB.
Leads module `ALL Leads` filter has the cvid = 1 and `columnindex` is the order, so change the value there to make first name appear before lastname.